# Why is Random.Range(0,3) generating only 0, 1 or 2 when 3 is supposed to be inclusive?

Tags: unity, c#, random

I'm currently having trouble getting my head around how *Random.Range()* and *Array[].Length* are working in the script below.

```
public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] animalPrefabs;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))
        {
            int animalIndex = Random.Range(0, animalPrefabs.Length);
            Instantiate(animalPrefabs[animalIndex], new Vector3(0, 0, 20), animalPrefabs[animalIndex].transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Array: Three Elements (0, 1 and 2)]

[image: Documentation: Random.Range()'s Minimum and Max are Inclusive]

Here, *animalIndex* is being assigned by *Random.Range()* a random number between 0 and the *animalPrefabs[]* array's length, which is 3. According to the documentation (both [Visual Studio's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAOS7.png) and [Unity's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)), both the minimum and maximum *Random.Range()* numbers are **inclusive**, which means *Random.Range()*'s possible outputs would amount to 4 numbers (0, 1, 2 and 3). However only 3 animalPrefabs[] (0, 1 and 2) are defined, as shown in the picture above.

Testing the script, however (printing *Random.Range()*'s outputs to the console), *Random.Range()* seems to be generating numbers from 0 to 2 only.

Is the documentation simply wrong? Otherwise, what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `public static int Range(int min, int max);`  overload, which as per the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html) is inclusive for the lower boundary, and exclusive for the upper boundary. The documentation you see in Visual Studio is for the version accepting floating point parameters. The overload accepting integers is documented below the floating point version on Unity's documentation page.